# AJAX Help needed

Tags: php, ajax, search

I've recently stumbled upon a small issue. Basically I'm trying to give my users the ability to search thru a certain category on my site, but the search is done via AJAX and will not reload the page, simply the content that is being searched through.

The following codes is what I came up with so far, but the only time where it will change something is when there will be no value in the textbox, other than that the content isnt being updated (I checked the PHP file manually and there is no erros & with HTTP Direct addon for Firefox I made sure the call to my php file is made)

My code:

category.php:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function showCat(str, cat)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("showCategory").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("showCategory").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  url="../cat_search.php?q="+str+"&cat="+cat

xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<input type="text" name="showCat" onkeyup="showCat(this.value, <?=$id?>)" style="width: 140px;" />

    <div id="showCategory">
     ## Stuff is being listed here on the load of the page & then should be updated with Ajax

   </div>
```

cat_search.php:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
include("global.php");

$q=$_GET["q"];
$cat=$_GET["cat"];

$search = $q;
$q = "%".$q."%";

$sql="SELECT * FROM games WHERE title like '$q' AND category = '$cat'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
echo "<center><div class=\"redbox\" style=\"width: 110px;\">No match</div></center>";
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo '......';
} ?>
```

The $id is the actual category ID.

Let me know if you would have the slighest idea of what my problem could be, I use almost the same exact code for another type of search and it works like a charm.

Thanks you!

Comment: Can you use Firebug (Firefox Add On) to see the AJAX requests as they happen - this will give you Js errors as well as show you when the AJAX request is and isn't being sent.

Comment: what happens if you search for `'`?

Comment: I tested on my computer; there is nothing wrong with the code you have posted here (except that it is wide open for SQL injection attacks). Were you able to verify with HTTP Direct that your PHP was returning something? Did you check your server's error logs for any fatal errors?

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery for AJAX. Seriously. It's very simple and painfulless. And WTH is that?

```
$q=$_GET["q"];
$search = $q;
$q = "%".$q."%";
```

Why not just?

```
$q = '%'.$_GET['q'].'%';
```

And, for example, a code in jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[name=showCat]').keyup(function(){
            showCat($(this).val(),$(this).attr('id'));
        });
    });
    function showCat(str,cat) {
        if (str == '') {
            $('#showCategory').html('');
            return;
        } else {
            $.get('../cat_search.php',{q:str,cat:cat},function(data){
                $('#showCategory').html(data);
            });
        }
    }
</script>

<input type="text" name="showCat" id="<?=$id?>" style="width: 140px;" />
<div id="showCategory">
    ## Stuff is being listed here on the load of the page & then should be updated with Ajax
</div>
```

Comment: I am a huge fan of jQuery. However, this answer does not help solve the problem. His JavaScript is correct and is working fine!